# Is there an "inset" alignment for a SkiaSharp stroke?

Tags: c#, drawing, gdi+, skiasharp

When using GDI I was able to set the [`Pen::Alignment` to `Inset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdiplus/-gdiplus-setting-pen-width-and-alignment-use), which drew the stroke on the inside of the path. Does SkiaSharp have a similar concept? I've scoured all the `SKPaint` documentation and haven't found what I'm looking for.

Comment: Would love to see the answer for this as well. So many say Skia is amazing and fast, but I'm finding it's not really a replacement for drawing with GDI+ - like at all. No flatten/widen paths, no inset pen alignments, no adjustable arrow caps, no compound array strokes, the list goes on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [GitHub Issues](https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp/issues/1107) page, there is not a direct way to do this. However, there are ways around it that I've found. For my purposes, I only need a monochrome black and white image, so my solution was to draw 2 rectangles, with a second, smaller rectangle on top of the first. The second rectangle is colored opposite of the first and is offset in size and position by the desired inset stroke width.

This method produces the following shapes:

[image]

Until Skia provides for this functionality directly, this is probably the most direct and reliable way to do this, at least in my monochrome use case.